# Probability exceeding 1?

Tags: probability

So I just finished learning Probability theory, past CLT and Order Statistics. But something still bothers me and it's from the axioms of probability. We know that for any event $E \subset S$ where $P(S) = 1$, we have $0 \leq P(E) \leq 1$.

Now take for example flipping a coin. The sample space for this experiment is $S = \{H,T\}$. 
Now consider another experiment, rolling a fair die: this sample space is $T = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. We know that $P(S) = 1$ and $P(T) = 1$. We also know that $P(S \cap T) = 0$. Therefore $P(S \cup T) = P(S) + P(T) = 1+ 1 = 2$. Where did I go wrong? Am I misinterperting something?

Comment: You can only meaningfully combine events that belong to the same sample space.

Comment: "$P$" defined on the set $S$ is a different "$P$" from the "$P$" defined on the set $T$. It is just convenient to use the same letter ($P$ - "probability") for both of those maps (as long as you never try to mix them up - which is what you did).

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a new sample space. Possible outcomes are ordered pairs (H,1), (H,2), (H,3),... (H,6), (T,1), (T,2), ....,(T,6), each having probability 1/12.